# How to use popup.html from URL in Chrome Extension?

Tags: url, google-chrome-extension, popup, external

I want to create an extension for Google Chrome, and it will be real simple.

I will have a database on my website's server, it will check if a URL is in the "blacklist" table, and warn the user if it is.

But I don't know where to start. I tried putting all the files on my web server, and changin the manifest.json file as such:
(changed the "default_popup" line)

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My Extension",
  "description": "This extension warns you if you are trying to open a blacklisted URL",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "http://www.mysite.com/my_extension/popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://secure.flickr.com/"
  ]
}
```

**Note** : this file resides on my computer, I load it from the "Extensions" menu of Chrome.

but when I tried to install this extension, I got the error :

```
This web page could not be found:chrome-extension://hgfdjnsakhkijfmdnadmlacgjggggkpf/http://www.mysite.com/my_extension/popup.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to hard code it in the manifest file, try putting something like this in a [`background page`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html):

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "http://www.mysite.com/my_extension/popup.html"});
```

However, it may not be possible to specify an external popup page at all.

Nevertheless, it would be better to include the popup in the extension files and then `get` *just* the data from your server.

Comment: It sounds just right, but then can a remote user be able to install this extension and run it in their own browser? I mean, don't I need a server to run the popup.html ?

Comment: @user223150 No, you don't need a server to host the popup and yes, it will work just fine if you have the file included, as it will be packaged with the rest of the extension.

Comment: thanks! I hope you would be interested in my new question about AJAX calls in chrome extensions :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959217/ajax-in-chrome-extensions